# Overflow issue in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, overflow, css

See this page in Chrome: http://jsbin.com/onariz/

Now it looks normal:

[image: looks normal, now doesn't it?]

Ok. Now if you have a scroll wheel on your mouse this is where you are going to want to use it.

Click with the scroll wheel in the scrollable area of the page and drag your mouse to the corner.

Now -- what the heck? Why does the page do this: 
[image: what the what? how the heck did it do that?]

Why would it do that?

How can I prevent that, or is this just a Google Chrome glitch? (I am using Chrome version 14.0.835)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98303

Comment: @Incognito i added this to the issue report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in newer version of Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89366